# Angular UI-Router: $state.current is sometimes undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ui.router` in my angular app, and in my navbar `controller` (which is included in more than one template) I wrote a simple `console.log($state.current)` to test it's behavior.

I've noticed that, sometimes, upon reload, the state is undefined:

```
Object {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}
```

and sometimes it is defined:

```
Object {url: "/admin", templateUrl: "app/components/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.html", controller: "AdminCtrl", controllerAs: "vm", name: "admin-dashboard"}
```

What might be the cause of this behavior and how can I guarantee that my state is defined when the view is loaded?

Comment: Is it undefined on load or reload, both?

Comment: @tjgienger both. But not always.

Comment: where did you write  the console.log statement?

Comment: Can we see your code? Since I've never experienced this, it would be the only way to help.

Comment: @Shaunak He said he put it in his header controller.

Comment: ah thanks.. missed it because of that explanation in parenthesis.
@Tiago: you need to provide more code for your route config, controllers and dom, however look at my answer for my best guess of what's going wrong for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surest way to get the right value in `$state.current` is to wait for the `$stateChangeSuccess` event to be fired by ui-router. Here's how you can do it:

In your Navbar controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    console.log($state.current)  // this should now always have a resolved value
})
```

Refer [ui-router wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) for more details.

**Why this works** as against only doing a `console.log($state.current)` is because, 
 $state.current has the right value only *'after'* the route is fully loaded. When you write it without the event, depending on where you write it, it can be a hit or miss. That's why you were getting inconsistent results. It's exactly for this reason that ui-router provides a success event, which promises that route has definitely been resolved.

Comment: This does indeed provide consistent results. Any guesses as to why $state.current isn't sufficient though?

Comment: Awesome. if that works then no guesses here:  it is not sufficient because $state.current has the right value only 'after' the route is fully loaded. When you write it without the event, depending on where you write it, it can be a hit or miss. That's why you were getting inconsistent results.  It's exactly for this reason that ui-router provides a success event, which promises that route has definitely been resolved

Comment: Great! Thank you for the detailed explanation.